# middleman new article .slim fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleman

I have been trying to use `middleman article 'test'` for example with the following config:

```
set :markdown_engine, :slim
activate :blog do |b|
  b.sources = "posts/{year}{month}{day}-{title}.html.slim"
  b.permalink = "{year}/{month}/{day}/{title}/index.html"
  b.new_article_template = "lib/templates/article.html.slim"
  b.layout = "layout-blog"
end
```

with gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'https://rails-assets.org'
ruby '2.1.0'

gem 'middleman', '~>3.3.3'
gem 'middleman-deploy'
gem 'middleman-pry'
gem 'middleman-blog'
gem 'slim'
gem 'pry'
gem 'font-awesome-middleman'
gem 'middleman-minify-html'
gem 'middleman-imageoptim', '~> 0.1.4'
gem 'rake'
gem 'highline'

gem 'rails-assets-jquery'

# Live-reloading plugin
gem 'middleman-livereload', '~> 3.1.0'

# For faster file watcher updates on Windows:
gem 'wdm', '~> 0.1.0', :platforms => [:mswin, :mingw]

# Windows does not come with time zone data
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mswin, :mingw]
```

but now matter what I try the new article is always generated as a `.markdown` file.

thoughts?

current error message:

```
middleman article 'test2'
/Users/chrishough/BusinessNoConformity/CodeNoConformity/Blog/.bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/middleman-core-3.3.3/lib/middleman-core/renderers/markdown.rb:40:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Tilt::SlimTemplate (NameError)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by adding the correct extension as follows:

```
activate :blog do |b|
  b.sources = "posts/{year}{month}{day}-{title}.html"
  b.permalink = "{year}/{month}/{day}/{title}/index.html"
  b.new_article_template = "lib/templates/article.html.erb"
  b.layout = "layout-blog"
  b.default_extension = ".slim"
end
```

[Middleman Post](https://github.com/middleman/middleman-blog/blob/master/lib/middleman-blog/template/config.tt)